# How to use robolectric to test started intent with extra data

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, robolectric

In an activity, I started a new Intent with some random extra data:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtra("key", generateRandomKey());
startActivity(newIntent);
```

I tested it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity, UserActivity.class);
Assert.assertThat(activity, new StartedMatcher(intent));
```

It's failed because the `intent` in my test code has not extra data `key`.

Since the `key` is random, it's hard to provide a same key. So I just want to test if the target class of the intent is `UserActivity`, but found no way to do it.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you extract the generateRandomKey() method into a separate class you can then inject (either manually or using something like RoboGuice) a controlled version of that class into your test so that the 'random' key generated when Robolectric runs is actually a known value. But is still random in the production code.

You can then catch the intent your activity creates and test if 'key' contains the expected test value.

---

However, to answer your question directly...

When I'm testing if an intent was generated (in this case by a button click) and is pointing to the correct target I use

```
public static void assertButtonClickLaunchesActivity(Activity activity, Button btn, String targetActivityName) {
    btn.performClick();
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
    Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);
    assertThat(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(), equalTo(targetActivityName));
}
```

Comment: This totally saved my day after trying Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks only to discover that Robolectric is not really starting the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Assert.assertTrue(UserActivity.class.equals(intent.getComponent().getClassName()));
```

or assertEquals?